# Wrapping text in pdf generator PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to wrap text as currently my text is going off the screen. The code below shows how I am printing my output. How do I make it so the text is displayed in a new line so it shows in my PDF document.

```
$page->drawText($this->_patient['referral_comments'], $xPos, $yPos);
```

How do I make it so the text is displayed in a new line so it shows in my PDF document.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How do I make it so the text is displayed in a new line so it shows in my PDF document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wordwrap():

> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5) wordwrap — Wraps a string to a given number of
>   characters

Example:

```
// You can change 250 as the width of your pdf
wordwrap($this->_patient['referral_comments'], 250, "\n");
```

EDIT: What you should do on your code:

```
$page->drawText(wordwrap($this->_patient['referral_comments'], 250, "\n"), $xPos, $yPos);
```

EDIT2: It seems that only wordwrap is not working, here is another suggestion:

```
$referral_comments = wordwrap($this->_patient['referral_comments'], 100, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $referral_comments ) as $textLine){
  if ($textLine!=='') {
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), $xPos, $yPos, 'UTF-8');
    $yPos -=14;
  }
}
```

What you do here is separate call to `$page->drawText` for each line.

Comment: I tried to use the code you posted and had no luck, am I supposed to add anything else to the above line?

Comment: I have tried the edited code and have also played around with the number. This did not seem to work, is there anything else you could possibly recommend?